# Identify last changed cell position in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

How can I identify the last updated cell with Google Script?
I have used this code so far, but if a change cell after the modification, the code identify the wrong cell position.

```
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
 var cell = sheet.getActiveCell();
```

Somehow I should identify the last updated/changed cell position.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should take a look at [Event Objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events), especially on [onEdit(e)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/#onedit) trigger

```
function onEdit(e){
  // Set a comment on the edited cell to indicate when it was changed.
  var range = e.range;
  range.setNote('Last modified: ' + new Date());
}
```

The *e* variable contains informations about the last modification on the Spreadsheet (Above, a example to get the modified range).

Comment: Can I limit the "changes the value of any cell in a spreadsheet" to only one column? 
  
`function onEdit(e){
  var sheet = e.getActiveSheet();
  var range = e.range;
  var sheetNameToWatch = "Test";
  
  if (sheet.getName() == sheetNameToWatch) {
     if(range.indexOf('G')!=-1){
        range.setNote('Last modified: ' + new Date());
     }
  }
}`

Comment: You can put a condition like if the range is part of that column, then..

Comment: Is that possible to call another function from onEdit() in order to be able to send email notification about the changes?

Comment: Sure. You can also keep notification information on a sheet and create a trigger who will send you all the notifications at once, to avoid some sort of spam (and avoid to send too many mail).

Comment: `function composeMessage(recipients,subject,body){
        var r = recipients;
        var s =subject;
        var b = body;
       MailApp.sendEmail(r,s,b);
}`

Comment: Can you send a sample of your code ? For debugging purpose .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141445/discussion-between-erika-and-pierre-marie-richard).